# Selenium JUnit test stuck at click()

Tags: java, testing, selenium, junit, webdriver

I made a quick test in Selenium IDE, and I exported it as Webdriver backed JUnit test. It works fine if every element exists on the page. I changed some of the locators to see what happens if Selenium couldn't find them and I found a strange problem:

Example 1:

```
selenium.click("link=Something");
```

'Something' doesn't exist, so my test stops within a few seconds with the exception: 
"com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: Element link=Something not found".

Example 2:

```
selenium.click("//div[2]/inprut");
```

Obviously the locator can't be found on the page (because of the typo), but the test doesn't fail, just simply stuck at this line.

Probably this is a silly question, but is it possible to make the click() function - used with the XPath locator -, behave like the one in Example 1? I'm a beginner with Selenium so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's great practice to add some backing logic to your code.   Typically you could `extend` your class to some `TestScript` class or something, but deeper down, you could implement a function like

```
public String getElement(String element) {
    try {
        if (isElementPresent(element)) return element;

        Integer timesIterated = 0;
        logInfo("Attempting to find element: [" + element + "]");

        for (timesIterated = 0; timesIterated < maxAttempts; timesIterated++) {
            if (isElementPresent(element)) {
                if (!isVisible(element)) logInfo("WARNING: [" + element + "] is not visible!");

                logStatus("Found");

                selenium.highlight(element);
                break;
            } else {
                Integer t = timesIterated + 1;
                logInfo(t.toString() + "/" + maxAttempts);
                if (timesIterated >= maxAttempts) logTestResult("Could not find [" + element + "]", false);
            }

            sleep(2);
        }

    } catch (Exception x) {
        logError(x.getMessage());
        end();
    }

    return element;
}
```

*please note that this is very arbitrary, and functions that i mention, won't exist for you. You'll have to implement them yourself. This is a snippet of actual code from my framework that I use that finds the element. if not, it will log an error, then fail the script.*

**EDIT**: This is relative to your question, because my `isElementPresent(String)` function works with both xpath, AND css...  So no matter what selector you provide, it will work.  So in your `isElementPresent(String)` function, implement the logic to support both selectors.